# Телеграм бот. Ошибка send_sticker. pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Не могу понять в чём дело, делаю всё по инструкции, а оно мне ошибку..
Телеграм бот должен лишь при команде `/start` писать приветственное сообщение со стикером. Стикер конечно не обязателен, но на этапе изучения хотелось бы и его.

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome (message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat_id, sti)

    bot.send_message(message.chat_id, 'Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b> бот, созданный для приготовления какао!'.format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "bot.py", line 9, in welcome
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat_id, sti)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'chat_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недоглядел, сидел минут 40 над этим, искал:

```
bot.send_sticker(message.chat_id, sti)
```

Ошибка была в `chat_id`, правильно было написать `chat.id`!